# Escaping metacharacters using grep on cygwin

Tags: regex, grep, escaping, cygwin

Using grep on cygwin to search for 'employee_id' with the following conditions:

- Not preceeded by an underscore
- Immediately followed by either space, closed bracket, or period

The expression that follows works in Regex Builder 2.05 using a sample of text, but does not return results when used in grep as such:

```
grep -E -r '[^_]employee_id[ \]\.]' ./*
```

I'm not sure if this is some peculiarity of entering expressions via command line, or if it has to do with differences between the many regex "dialects", but I haven't come across any alternative way of escaping characters in my search for an answer.

Can someone provide the correct grep syntax to return the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -E -r '(^|[^_])employee_id[] .]' .
```

- `(^|[^_])` as `employee_id` can be at line start or be preceded by any non underscore character.
- There is no need to escape DOT or `]` inside character class. But keep in mind that closing `]` **must immediately follow** opening `[`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Good catch on the first point, and I didn't think about not needing to escape the dot, but that makes sense.  Unfortunately, your solution also returned no results, though I know there are matches.

Comment: I have actually updated it just before your comment. Use `grep -E -r '(^|[^_])employee_id[] .]' .`

Comment: Very interesting!  I wondered before if I didn't escape the closed bracket if it would catch that there was another closed bracket enclosing the character class, but it didn't work.  I see now that the closed bracket has to immediately follow the open bracket, and I hadn't thought of that.  Thanks for your help!